# Make same class elements fixed only while scrolling pass their parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery so trying to solve this has started to drive me insane,  basically what I want is to add a "fixed" class to a child element while I scroll through it's parent element and remove it when I scroll pass it.

I found a good example on this [website](http://oh-so-coco.tumblr.com). To the right,  the time and tags follow the post in the blog and remain static as you scroll pass their parent element.  I want to know how to replicate this effect

Comment: Okay so now you expect us to program it for you? How much are you paying?

Comment: Use `Save Page as` option.

Comment: Checkout these $(window).scroll, $(window).scrollTop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here, check the demos.

#### link http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Answer (score 0):

add the following

css style:

```
    <style>
       p.pos_fixed
        {
          position:fixed;
          top:30px;
          right:5px;
        }
     </style>
```

then HTML

```
<p class="pos_fixed">Some more text</p>
```